# regular expression pattern for any string with specific length including new line

Tags: php, expression

I need to build a pattern for preg_match that will accept string between 0 - 2000 chars including new lines  (\n)
I ended up with :

> /^.{0,2000}$/

but don't know how to add "new line" in it. It accept anything from 0 to 2000 chars but doesn't accept new lines. Where to add "new line" into this pattern ?

Comment: why do you need a regex for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the [multiline modifier](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers) (Update: just realised, that you probably need the "dotall"-modifier `s` too. try it out)

```
/^.{0,2000}$/ms
```

However, its faster and more convenient to use common string functions

```
strlen($string) <= 2000
```